# How to Decode SCT List from SSL cert in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asn.1, asn1crypto

I am currently doing this :

```
        var extensions = (certificate.Extensions ?? new X509ExtensionCollection()).Cast<X509Extension>();
        var sctExtension = extensions.Where(x => x.Oid.Value.Equals("1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2")).FirstOrDefault();
       AsnEncodedData asndata = new AsnEncodedData(sctExtension.Oid, sctExtension.RawData);

       string sctListLines = asndata.Format(true); // This returns the SCT list with each field on a new line
```

But format is not decoding the SCT in the human readable form. Can someone advise me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/2018/04/04/sct-encoding.html explains how to decode this data. The data itself is ASN1 encoded but contains TLS encoded binary data in it: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-4

Comment: Thanks for the link ! it helped me to decode it!!!